# Discord.js v13 Mongoose || Delete members' data when they left the server

Tags: mongoose, discord.js

I'm working with mongoDB when I ran into a problem: My code didn't work when I tried to delete data when someone left. Here's my code:

````js
const Event = require("../Structures/Event.js");

const Discord = require("discord.js");

const ProfileModels = require('../Models/profileSchema.js')

module.exports = new Event("guildMemberRemove", async (client, message) => {

    await ProfileModels.findOneAndDelete({
        userID: member.id,
        serverID: member.guild.id
    });
    


});```
````

Comment: This is just a guess, but is member defined after `userID` and `serverID` in your Event?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't defined `member` on your current code, only `client, message`. So try to change it to `client, member`

```js
const Event = require("../Structures/Event.js");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const ProfileModels = require('../Models/profileSchema.js')
module.exports = new Event("guildMemberRemove", async (client, member) => {

    await ProfileModels.findOneAndDelete({
        userID: member.id,
        serverID: member.guild.id
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried exactly like you and It still didn't work.